# Geany doesn't recognize admin:// URI

Tags: gedit, geany

`gedit admin:///etc/fstab` correctly opens fstab on write mode and asks for admin password. But with geany it returns:

```
phil@GLaDOS:~$ geany admin:///etc/fstab
Unable to find file « admin:///etc/fstab »
```

It seems that geany doesn't know admin://, is there a way to solve that?

Comment: I came across a suggestion that you need to add your user to the `fuse` group with `sudo gpasswd -a ${USERNAME} fuse`. This helps with applications such as Geany. [Source from eight years ago](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/521).

Comment: I already have gvfs-fuse installed, yet the `fuse` group doesn't exists, nor the `~/.gvfs/` folder

Comment: Sorry! I don't use the GNOME environment and don't know more on the topic.